# To save file descriptor output to a string variable

Tags: bash, redirect

How to save file descriptor output to a string variable, v, instead of to stdout like illustrationn fd3 below:

```
exec 3>&1; echo foo >&3

v=    #... ? in order to quivalently be v='foo'
```

Comment: Hmm, I may have misunderstood what you want. Do you really want `echo foo >&3` there? It'll be doing the same as `echo foo` since both are streaming to `stdout`

Comment: You're Fine !! actually `echo foo >&3`in another process environment

Comment: Ok, so, does the answer I made work? I'm still not sure I understood your question correctly :-)

Comment: But meant it really in a simple, elegant way of Unix named pipe feature... ibeen thinking on it

Comment: Are you asking if it can be done without using a temporary file? If that's what you're asking I think that'll be even more complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way could be to redirect stdout to a file.

```
#!/bin/bash

tempfile="$(mktemp)"       # create a temporary file

trap "rm '$tempfile'" EXIT # remove the temporary file when the script exits

exec 3>&1                  # dup stdout to 3
exec 1>"$tempfile"         # redirect stdout to the temporary file

echo Hello                 # this output is
echo World                 # now redirected to the temporary file

exec 1>&3                  # dup stdout back to the original
v=$(cat "$tempfile")       # read the temporary file

echo "Got: $v"
```

Output:

```
Got: Hello
World
```